# IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Функция должна считать сумму чисел из 3 столбца для каждого уникального имени из 1  столбца, но выдает ошибку индекса после того как посчитает 1 имя.

код:

```
def db_read():
    global row_sum
    curs.execute('SELECT * FROM sheet')
    row_sum = 0
    ind = 0
    for row in curs.fetchall():
        name_pos = row[ind]
        if name_pos == row[ind]:
            row_sum += int(row[2])
            ind = ind + 1
            print(row_sum)
            print(ind)
        elif name_pos != row[ind]:
            print('elif')
```

принт:

```
2500
1
5000
2
8500
3
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\pyt_prjct\prog1\main.py", line 18, in db_read
    name_pos = row[ind]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: ind сохраняет свое значение и нужно его обнулить при переходе к следующей строке.

Comment: Но тогда он не будет отделять имена, а просто засуммирует все строки

Comment: Я указал, в чем причина. А что "он" будет делать, зависит от того, что будет написано в коде.

Comment: Очевидно, кортеж `row` имеет длину в три элемента, и когда `ind` равен 3, попытка обратиться к четвёртому элементу кортежа (счёт начинается с нуля) завершается этой ошибкой. Не пытайтесь получить доступ к тому, чего не существует.